# Fabric.js, manually triggering mouse:enter/leave, mouse:move

Tags: fabricjs, aframe

I am currently working on a way to proxy synthetic events emitted from an A-Frame plane containing a fabric.js-initialised canvas texture. The goal is to allow the user to drag and drop fabric items as if they were interacting with a 2D canvas.  All of the logic is handled so now I just want to be able to, for example, programatically grab and item under 0,0, drag it to 10, 10 and let go of it.

When I inspected the event parameter in a 'mouse:out' handler I noticed the object had an 'e' parameter which was a MouseEvent instance.  So I tried something like this:

```
let eventOptions = {
  clientX,
  clientY,
  bubbles: true,
  button: 1
}

let fabricCanvas = this.components.draw.fabricCanvas
let e = new MouseEvent(event.type, eventOptions)
fabricCanvas.trigger(aFrameEvtToFabricEvt[event.type], { e })
```

That didn't seem to work. Nor did providing eventOptions as the second param of the trigger method. Nor did calling the private handler methods on fabric canvas i.e. _onMouseMove.

Is there any way to achieve this otherwise?

Comment: Did some debuging trigger function and the reason why trigger will never cause drag/drop functionality is because the trigger(fire) function will always return if there are no specific event handlers registered for those events.  The event handlers for drag and drop functionality must be handled elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

So fabricCanvas gets the event from an element that is overlaid on the canvas and trigger some event listeners.

The best thing would be forward the events directly to the listeners, with the right pattern. mousedown, mousemove, mouseup.

```
let eventOptions = {
  clientX,
  clientY,
  bubbles: true,
  button: 1
}
```

if this event is correct, just exec

```
fabricCanvas._onMouseDown(e)
fabricCanvas._onMouseMove(eAnotherPoint)
fabricCanvas._onMouseUp(eAnotherPoint)
```

This should work

Please check what kind of `button/buttons/which` is using fabric to understand left/right/middle click.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will try to investigate possibility.  The problem is that the fabric canvas doesn't seem to be in the DOM.  Do you know if there is a way to access the listener element by reference ?

Comment: EDIT: I found the event capture as fabricCanvas.upperCanvasEl

Comment: Triggering events on the eventCapture element as such fails.  ```let e = new MouseEvent(event.type, eventOptions)
          fabricCanvas.upperCanvasEl.dispatchEvent(e)```.  I also tried dispatching on the container which also fails.  Only events fired through the canvas.trigger cause corresponding event listeners to fire but there seems to be no way to create mouse events (aside from a click) this way.

Comment: i ll try, i need to setup a fiddle. i belive it should work

Comment: That's very kind of you to offer, I would really apprecate your help.  Thanks for your contribution.  You will help me make a VR version of this http://playful-geometer.net/polyhedron-designer/

Comment: @J.Barca - did you ever get this to work? I tried this suggestion, but doesn't seem to work.